# Embedding a font to HTML

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I'm trying to embed the font "Andale Mono" to my html pages, I have the font in the following extensions: .eot, .svg, .ttf and .woff

Is there anyway that I can get it to work on all browsers?? I was able to get it work fine on Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but it's not working on IE.

Here is what I last found:

```
@font-face {
       font-family: 'Andale Mono';
       src: url('AndaleMono-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), url('AndaleMono-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('AndaleMono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, easiest way to do it is to use [fontsquirrel.com](http://fontsquirrel.com)

Comment: Thank ! it finally did work, but in the demo the following line was used: font: 18px/27px 'AndaleMonoRegular', Arial, sans-serif; I'm wondering, what does the 18px/27px does??

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PTSansNarrowBold';
    src: url('styles/PTN77F-webfont.eot');
    src: url('styles/PTN77F-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('styles/PTN77F-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('styles/PTN77F-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('styles/PTN77F-webfont.svg#webfontSTdD4QCq') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```